# How to foreach on subscribe

Tags: angular6, angular7, subscribe

I am tryying to loop through a observable but it is saying undefined. why is it so.

This is my API responce

```
[
  {
    "id": 5,
    "name": "Ram",
    "description": "desc",
    "active": false
  },
  {
    "id": 4,
    "name": "Ram",
    "description": "desc",
    "active": false
  },
  ]
```

But I want to filter it a way like this

```
 this.model.users = [
      {uId: 1, uNAme: Ram},
    ];
```

So, for this to achieve I would need to loop through my subscribe but it is saying undefined

```
 export class TestComponent implements OnInit {
    usersArray: User[];
   response: any;

    constructor(private service: MyService) {
    this.service.get(this.requestModel).subscribe(users => this.response = users);
     this.response.forEach(element => {
    this.usersArray.push({
      uId: element.id,
      uNAme: element.name
    });
   });

      this.model.users = this.usersArray;
    }
```

Model

```
 export class User {
     public uId: number;
     public uNAme: string;
 }
```

serice:

```
get(requestSearch: ProjectRequest): Observable<any> {
  return this.http.post<any>(this.projectUrl, requestSearch,  httpOptions);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, so your problem is that your running on the response before you get the response
because your using observable your application keep on running and not does not stop at
the subscribe.

what you can do is basically like this:

```
 export class TestComponent implements OnInit {
    usersArray: User[];
   response: any;

    constructor(private service: MyService) {
    this.service.get(this.requestModel).subscribe(users =>{
     this.response = users;
     this.response.forEach(element => {
        this.usersArray.push({
        uId: element.id,
        uNAme: element.name
    });
   });
  }

    );
      this.model.users = this.usersArray;
    }
```

But I would consider use filter() and not using the foreach. //not good idea.

Ok, after reading more properly, all you have to do is use Map() function like this:

```
this.service.get(this.requestModel).subscribe(users =>{
  this.response = users.map((user)=>{
    return {uId:user.id, uNAme: user.name}
  })
}
```

good luck and enjoy :)

Comment: Can you please show me how to use filters in above ?

Comment: @Sweetie I`ve edited my answer, you can look now.
and if you find it useful it will be nice if u set it as the correct answer.

Comment: can you please also let me know that the map you have used is of type script or it is of rxjx?

Comment: @Sweetie its es6(JavaScript)

Answer (score 2):

Change your service call like the below one and hope it will work.

```
export class TestComponent implements OnInit {
usersArray: User[];
response: any;

constructor(private service: MyService) {
    this.service.get(this.requestModel).subscribe((data: any) => {
        this.response = data;

        this.response.forEach(element => {
            this.usersArray.push({
             uId: element.id,
             uNAme: element.name
            });
        }); 
    }
    this.model.users = this.usersArray;
}
}
```